# How do I restore/call an original function after it's redefined?

Tags: lua, luajit

I'm using LuaJIT 2.1 and when I need to hide the source code, I first obfuscate it to prevent the script from being decompiled, and then compile it.

We know that we can hook any function in LUA just by redefining it:

```lua
local __load = load
load = function(data, ...)
    -- some stuff, e.g. you can unpack the data var to a file
    return __load(data, ...)
end
```

And if somebody joins my script with their one (e.g. above), they can literally hook any built-in and global function in my script, as well as to access to global variables and functions that I defined myself (this is why I always define all functions and variables as local ones).

So, the question is how I can call their original functions or at least restore them to their original chunks. If that's even possible ofc.

---

Possible answers that won't help:

- `_G['function_name']` contains the address to a new function.
- Checking functions with `pcall(string.dump, function_name)` is a good thing, but it can be hooked as well.

---

If you can't understand something I said:

- by "joining script," I mean combining them with each other using `load` or `loadstring`, after that these scripts have access to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Lua sandboxing is based on the assumption that a compiled chunk is *your* compiled chunk. If someone has the ability to hook into the Lua script loading process and attach arbitrary stuff to your Lua scripts before the compiler sees them, then you can't sandbox them away. That's your point of failure in the security process, so that's what you have to defend against. Which requires tools well outside of the boundaries of Lua itself.

Note however, that if you are loading a *pre-compiled* chunk, a user (limited to only regular Lua script) cannot add stuff onto the end of that chunk. At least, not in regular Lua 5.1; LuaJIT's loader may be different. Granted, if they've swapped the `load` function, then they could also edit the bytecode itself, so if they've gotten that far, you're still out of luck.

---

The thing about Lua sandboxing is that it cannot be done from within the script. Whatever environment your script is presented with (globals and such) is that environment. That is managed by the code that loads and executes your script. If it doesn't explicitly do anything to isolate global changes made by one script from another, then there's nothing your script can do about that.

Comment: so this means we can't protect our scripts from external intervention without rebuilding lua51.dll? literally anyone can break into your compiled scripts because the `load` function can load a compiled script (byte-code), no matter if it's a lua or luajit compiled script. it's pretty easy actually

Comment: @user70960: Are you sure about that? I wrote a test script that attempts to take two pre-compiled chunks and shove them both into `load`, and only the first one chunk executed. I even stitched the two precompiled strings together and shoved them into `loadstring`, and it still only executed the first. Now, I'm using baseline Lua 5.1 rather than LuaJIT, so that might be the difference. But that would be odd behavior from LuaJIT.

Comment: @user70960: [Here is my test script](https://gist.github.com/NicolBolas/79310803c8008774a37c4ab6d0d200f0) if you want to try it yourself.

Comment: @user70960: These scripts are not "joined", nor do they "have access to each other". That's simply one script being executed before another, with no attempt at sandboxing at all. Your question suggested that `load` *itself* had been overridden, and thus you've lost control over your sandbox. But you haven't. The example you showed doesn't even attempt sandboxing for those scripts. So, do you have control over the code that is compiling/executing these scripts, or don't you?

Comment: you got it wrong. i'll make a video so you can see what i mean and how it works.

Comment: @user70960: OK, before you make a video displaying simple things, remember: I know Lua. I know what globals are and how they work. I know what happens when you execute a function that sets global variables, followed by a function that uses global variables. So if all you're going to show in that video is how that example code executes, that is a waste of time. I know how that code works, and I know how it exhibits your problem. I'm saying that your *question* strongly suggests a very different problem, one that is more than just a matter of basic sandboxing.

Comment: I think the problem is the obfuscation part - but... Well yes obviously as soon as you distribute in a hostile environment (hence your need to obfuscate), you are in danger of having your source code altered. The solution is to not have critical code in a hostile system.

Comment: https://youtu.be/h0_rnFBnev4 - maybe you're right that i can't modify a compiled chunk (actually i can, but it's not about Lua), but i still can manipulate built-in and global functions. I tried reading about sandboxing, but nothing really helped.

Comment: @user70960: Now that the problem has been localized, you need to explain what tools you have available. That is, what code is "your" code in this scenario? Is the code that loads and executes scripts "your" code or does it belong to someone else? Can that code be modified to provide proper sandboxing for dealing with potentially malicious scripts?

Comment: @NicolBolas since I'm trying to protect my scripts, 'my script.luac' would be mine (but it needs to be obfuscated first), and the rest would belong to a hacker trying to hack my script. What "that code" are you talking about? Joiner is mine, it just turns a script into a table and then load it.

Comment: @NicolBolas even if we try to protect some functions using others, they could be hooked too - https://youtu.be/ahhZtu-4e5w i think the possibility to redefine any function is a huge security breach in Lua and there's nothing we can do, at least without rebuilding lua51.dll (maybe?).

Comment: @user70960: First, stop posting Youtube videos; the compression is too great to see anything, and even if it wasn't, I can't copy/paste anything. Second, if you have no control over the program that is actually loading and executing your scripts, then you have no control over anything. You cannot sandbox Lua from within the sandbox you're trying to build. Your scripts are at the mercy of the environment that loads and executes them. Always.

Comment: @NicolBolas okay, i got it, thanks. Regarding the videos quality, they are 1080p